# Accessing elements in list of dictionary values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dict with such a structure:

```
([('key1', [('A1', 'B1', 'C1'), ('A2', 'B2', 'C2')]), ('key2', [('A1', 'B1', 'C1')])])
```

For each key, there might be up to 5 triples attributed to it and there are about 1000 keys.

I would like to access each `B` element in the triple and cluster the keys according to these in the form of a list. So in this case, `B1` would consist of `key1` and `key2`, whilst `B2` would have just `key1` in it.

I am having trouble working out how to access each of the second elements of triples. How do I go about this?

Comment: This is not a `dict`.

Comment: This is not a code-writing service. Accessing data like this is relatively straightforward, and there are probably thousands of questions that address such an issue. Have you looked at other questions and couldn't get them to work? How did your attempts fail? *What were your attempts*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to build a `dict` given the list of tuples, it could be done like:

```
    result = {}
    for key, items in data:
        for it1, it2, it3 in items:
            if it2 not in result:
                result[ it2 ] = []
            result[ it2 ].append( key )
```